# Xamarin: Determine if element in GetSpans() is bold or italic?

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

**Native Android** `Spanned.getSpans(......,SyleSpan.class)` function return type `StyleSpan[]`

**Xamarin** `ISpanned.GetSpans(......)` function returns type `Java.lang.Object[]` though it returns `<T>` (`T`=`StyleSpan` in my case) in native android. Therefore there is a loss of information since the Mono interface doesn't expose what it would have been exposed if I had used the native SDK.

Since propery `Style` (`getStyle()` in native android) is only available in `StyleSpan` there is no way to read that a given StyleSpan read through GetSpans is bold or italic.

Any ideas how I determine **bold** or *italic*?

Is this a limitation in the mono interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do everything. ;) There is just no comfortable generic wrapper for the `GetSpans` method.

```
ISpanned ss = ...;
var spans = ss.GetSpans(0, 20, Class.FromType(typeof(SyleSpan)));
foreach (SyleSpan span in spans)
{
    // do what you want
    if(span.Style == TypefaceStyle.Bold)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Xamarin can find bold spans, too :)");
    }
}
```

if you want to access it generic:

```
public static class ISpannedExtension
{
    public static TSpan[] GetSpans<TSpan>(this ISpanned ss, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        return ss.GetSpans(startIndex, length, Class.FromType(typeof(TSpan)))
            .Cast<TSpan>()
            .ToArray();
    }
}

// usage
ISpanned ss = ...;
var spans = ss.GetSpans<SyleSpan>(0, 20);
```

Comment: working perfectly thanks.
I actually tried to cast this (which should work), but instead casting each Java.Lang.Object into StyleSpan I had casted array Object[] into StyleSpan[] which obviously didn't work. 

So when casting fails I thought they are fundamentally Lang.Objects rather than StyleSpans.

Only realized the mistake after reading this answer.